# Passive variable in JavaScript for a pet is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a pet tied to a radio button. When you change radio buttons the passive should go away. I have it where exp stops increasing but my strength value won't go back down to the default (strength is number under radio button)

[image]

Default is 2 for strength so when the radio button is on strength is 2 + `turtlestrength`, I need it to go back down to 2 when you change buttons.

I've tried to mess around with if statements / settimeout but nothing seems to be working.

I expect on level up for `Turtlestrength` to go up by 1 in value and on radio button change for the passive addition to strength to be taken away( for it to go back down to 2 in this case).  But the actual result on the button changes the value of strength stays combined with Turtlestrength and when I click back on the button it adds Turtlestrength to strength. This 2nd part should be an easy fix if strength just gets updated correctly on button change. Also on level up, Turtlestrength is not updating to be 1 higher ( for example at lv 1 I had 3 total strength passively but when I level It should go up to 4 but it stays at 3.

```js
var Turtle = 1;
var Turtlelv = 1;
var TurtleCexp = 0;
var TurtleMexp = 100;
var NextMaxTurtleExp = TurtleMexp;
var Turtlestrength = 1;
var Strength = 2;

function turtleandstrength (){  
  if (document.getElementById("turtle-radio").checked) {
    Strength = Strength + Turtlestrength
    document.getElementById("Strength").innerHTML = Strength;
  } else {
    Strength = Strength - Turtlestrength
    document.getElementById("Strength").innerHTML = Strength;
  }
}

function turtleXpUp() {
  if (document.getElementById("turtle-radio").checked && TurtleCexp < 
    TurtleMexp) {
    setTimeout(turtleXpUp, 200)
    TurtleCexp = TurtleCexp + 1;
    document.getElementById("TurtleCexp").innerHTML = TurtleCexp;
  } 

  if (TurtleCexp >= TurtleMexp) {
    Turtlelv = Turtlelv + 1;
    TurtleCexp = 0;
    Turtle = Turtle + 1;
    Turtlestrength = Turtlestrength + 1;
    NextMaxTurtleExp = NextMaxTurtleExp * 1.5;
  }

  document.getElementById("Strength").innerHTML = Strength;
  document.getElementById('TurtleMexp').innerHTML = NextMaxTurtleExp;
  document.getElementById('Turtlelv').innerHTML = Turtlelv;
  document.getElementById('TurtleCexp').innerHTML = TurtleCexp;
  //document.getElementById('Turtle').innerHTML = Turtle; 
}

document.getElementById("turtle-radio").addEventListener("change", turtleXpUp);
document.getElementById("turtle-radio").addEventListener("change", turtleandstrength);
document.getElementById("Strength").innerHTML = Strength;
```

```html
<div class="control">
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="Pets" id="turtle-radio">
    </label>
    <img src="turtle.png" alt="turtle" height="100" width="100">Lv
    <span id="Turtlelv">1</span>
    <span id="TurtleCexp">0</span> /
    <span id="TurtleMexp">100</span>
    <br />
    <span id="Strength">0</span>
    <br />
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="Pets" id="dog-radio">
    </label>
```

Comment: So you just want to `Strength = 2;` at the top of `turtleXpUp`? I would just have one change function, personally.

Comment: What do you mean by "passive"? That's not a standard HTML or JavaScript concept that I know of.

Comment: never mind i have variables

Comment: like in a rpg. if you equipt a sword you get a passive boost to strength by 5. if you take off that sword your character should lose those stats. if you have cloths on in real life you have a passive resistence to cold. if you where naked that passive cold resistance would go away.

Comment: so from the code snippet you can see that when it goes to level 2 the value of 3 should change to 4(it doesn't).

Comment: and when you switch buttons the strength value should go back down to 2 not stay at 3

Comment: Just an advice, but common practice is to use lower-case letters for the first letter in a variable name. The use of an upper-case letter usually signifies that it's the name of a class, or an instance of a class. Of course, your script will run fine either way, but it might be easier for others reading your code if you use these conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add an event listener on the other radio button, the `Strength` will go down when you switch the button.

Add this after event listener for `turtle-radio`:

```
document.getElementById("dog-radio").addEventListener("change", turtleandstrength);
```

Comment: same question as other one when a level up happens the strength value doesnt change from 3 to 4. how do i fix this. where do i do a documentbyid

Comment: @tmanrocks994 I think your problem here is that you only update the `Turtlestrength` variable on level up, but the value you are showing on the page is the value of the `Strength` variable. You need to update the value of `Strength` on level up if you want the change to reflect on the page.

Comment: hey so i fixed mine up but what if i switch between 2 different buttons?  http://prntscr.com/nv7scq  when i click between turtle and lizard it minuses 1 from strength http://prntscr.com/nv7si8

Comment: note i did change the wolfs passive to be what the turtle was , turtle has nothing now i did convert everything. im just confused on how to prevent changes between other buttons. like wolf to turtle i added that addevent listen just now but if i do turtle button to lizard or vice versa it minuses 1 from strength

Comment: if you are still online id love some help fixing this might just convert what skyline did if i cant figure it out

Comment: @tmanrocks994 If you're going to include multiple animals, then I would suggest that you rethink the structure of your code before it gets out of hand. It will be much easier to comprehend, and to make changes if you use the same functions,  and store all animals in the same array or object. I will go on lunchbreak very soon and I could help you create a mock-up structure if you'd like. I can link you a pastebin link or something when I'm done.

Comment: I would love that. it doesn't have to be on your lunch break tho whenever is good. haven't used much arrays in javascript. but if it can make creating 6-10 pets for this game easier it would help

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nv8xkj  I want to do that for like 8 different pets( prob only 4 on release of the game) and for equipment

Comment: I did a more scalable version of your initial code here: https://pastebin.com/GqrqpeGu If you look at the code I think you can understand the design patterns. So for example, you can just add more animals to the `animals` object and just add a radio button for them, and they can be selected too. You should try now for yourself to use the kind of scalable design I showed here and add more features that you need :) The best way by far to learn, is by doing!

Comment: thanks i will look more into it tomorrow. I had no idea you could do that sort of stuff in javascript. http://prntscr.com/nv9n5f this is at the bottom of my pets javascript btw to give eatch one a unlock condition. some from a lving skill tree, some from quests. i really want 8 in total but at the moment http://prntscr.com/nv9nyt  Im not sure why the turtle is so far down. Im still working on my own art for the 2nd 2 but the first one i made the others are just place holders. how would i fit 4 on left side and 4 on the right. i feel like the turtle should be able to be put right under the pets

Comment: Trying to go to sleep I usually work on this on my off days from work.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nvo0fa  I did try you code but i really want it sideways like this with each option next to a picture . how can i formate what you gave me to be one pet after another ?   http://prntscr.com/nvo0uv I also get a error having a => sign next to (radio)

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nvo67i  I have it nice and neat but how do I make the Lv Exp / stuff not be visible until one is selected. also the strength increase should be tied to the wolf but the last function isnt working http://prntscr.com/nvo6ht How do i only make wolf have the buff and not every animal? i wanted the lizard to give a magic buff and the turtle to give a hp and mana regen buff.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194211/discussion-between-azer-and-tmanrocks994).

Comment: im in that chat. ill be on my pc for next 4-5 hours if u wana help me. I think i found a way i can do it might make a new question asking how to fix radio buttons so if i switch from turtle to lizard it doesn't minus strength by 1

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `change` event doesn't fire on a radio button when it becomes unchecked, only when it is checked. You can add a simple `console.log()` message at the top of your function to see that the function only runs when the radio button is checked. This means that your `else` condition where you remove the strength never happens.

You'll have to add a `change` event to all of the radio buttons and check which one is checked. There are several answers on stackoverflow that cover a similar scenario, but something like this would work:

```js
var turtleRadio = document.getElementById("turtle-radio");
var dogRadio = document.getElementById("dog-radio");
var turtleInterval;

var Turtle = 1;
var Turtlelv = 1;
var TurtleCexp = 0;
var TurtleMexp = 100;
var NextMaxTurtleExp = TurtleMexp;
var Turtlestrength = 1;
var Strength = 2;

// This is an event dispatcher function. Based on the radio
// button that was clicked, run different functions.
function radioChanged(event) {
  if (event.target === turtleRadio) {
    turtleandstrength(true);
    turtleXpUp(true);
    // Run other functions...
  } else if (event.target === dogRadio) {
    turtleandstrength(false);
    turtleXpUp(false);
    // Run other functions...
  }
}

function turtleandstrength(turtleChecked) {
  if (turtleChecked) {
    Strength = Strength + Turtlestrength
    document.getElementById("Strength").innerHTML = Strength;
  } else {
    Strength = Strength - Turtlestrength;
    if (Strength < 2) Strength = 2;
    document.getElementById("Strength").innerHTML = Strength;
  }
}

function turtleXpUp(turtleChecked) {
  clearInterval(turtleInterval);

  if (turtleChecked && TurtleCexp < TurtleMexp) {
    turtleInterval = setInterval(function () { turtleXpUp(turtleChecked); }, 200);
    TurtleCexp = TurtleCexp + 1;
    document.getElementById("TurtleCexp").innerHTML = TurtleCexp;
  } 

  if (TurtleCexp >= TurtleMexp) {
    Turtlelv = Turtlelv + 1;
    TurtleCexp = 0;
    Turtle = Turtle + 1;
    Turtlestrength = Turtlestrength + 1;
    Strength = Strength + 1;
    NextMaxTurtleExp = NextMaxTurtleExp * 1.5;
  }

  document.getElementById("Strength").innerHTML = Strength;
  document.getElementById('TurtleMexp').innerHTML = NextMaxTurtleExp;
  document.getElementById('Turtlelv').innerHTML = Turtlelv;
  document.getElementById('TurtleCexp').innerHTML = TurtleCexp;
  //document.getElementById('Turtle').innerHTML = Turtle; 
}

//document.getElementById("turtle-radio").addEventListener("change", turtleXpUp);
//document.getElementById("turtle-radio").addEventListener("change", turtleandstrength);
turtleRadio.addEventListener("change", radioChanged);
dogRadio.addEventListener("change", radioChanged);
document.getElementById("Strength").innerHTML = Strength;
```

```html
<div class="control">
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="Pets" id="turtle-radio">
    </label>
    <img src="turtle.png" alt="turtle" height="100" width="100">Lv
    <span id="Turtlelv">1</span>
    <span id="TurtleCexp">0</span> /
    <span id="TurtleMexp">100</span>
    <br />
    <span id="Strength">0</span>
    <br />
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="Pets" id="dog-radio">
    </label>
```

Note I also changed `setTimeout` to `setInterval` as that is the functionality you're really looking for.

Comment: thanks this works in the snippet but after a lv up its not updateing the strength value. how would i fix that.  i will also prob add math.floor to the next cost thing so its not a decimal number

Comment: That's because your `turtleXpUp` function never adds `Strength + turtlestrength` to update the value. I've added it in

Comment: ty for the information but when i tried to do your exactly in brackets editor (i can never get setinterval to work in there) setinterval does not work. If you can change it back to settimeout that would help me. If its to hard to do that's ok i did try on my own to but It didn't work for me.

Comment: @tmanrocks994 can you elaborate on "it didn't work for me"? What didn't work? Do you get error messages? If you run the code snippet above, the code runs as expected, so it definitely works.

Comment: yea but in brackets editor set intervals dont work like that. i tried formating it exactly like you did everything worked except the setinterval functions there wasnt any error messages

Comment: i'll post mine changed. sigh I just want this to work. i'm pretty sure i followed yours to a T. but the setinterval wont go off.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nw5te6   ok i got it to work after some some but I need to change what i wanted in my outcome. i want strength to go back to its value before the radio button was selected not 2. Strength could be any number because i have other upgrade to it outside the pets tab. like a skill tree and a leveling system. i also wanted to put it on weapons. I will prob get the issue i got with Azers answer where if i switch from turtle to lizard after the change to strength not equaling  2 strength will go down by 1 even tho it shouldn't.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nw5ued    http://prntscr.com/nw5uir    here's what i did for the code